# How to bulk upload images in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is the code that i use now, this works for uploading single images, but i want the option to choose multiple images at the same time and upload them to the s3 bucket.

```
public function create() {
    return view(view: 'images.create');
}

public function store(Request $request) {
    $path = $request -> file(key: 'image') -> store(path: 'images', options: 's3');

    $image = Image::create([
    'filename' => basename($path),
    'url' => Storage::disk(name: 's3') -> url($path)
    ]);

    return $image;
}

public function show(Image $image) {
    return $image -> url;
}
```

I have been looking into the answer to this question: [Uploading multiple files to Amazon S3 from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888115/uploading-multiple-files-to-amazon-s3-from-php)

But struggle to understand and how to implement it into my own code.

Comment: You would modify this code to use a `foreach()` loop over `$request->files()` instead of `$request->file()`, and adjust your request to send multiple images (like `input type="file" multiple`, etc (you didn't show how you're sending your file, so we can't help with that unless you edit your code)

Comment: Thanks, Tim for the tip! I haven't written any code yet on how to send the file, I just tested with postman.

Comment: No worries! Off the top of my head for Postman, I'm not sure how to send multiple images (although I'm quite sure there's a way, Postman is pretty robust), but see what you can find and feel free to update your question with more details if you run into any issues. Cheers! 